# How do I redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, redirect, amazon-s3

I recently transferred my website to AWS and added an SSL certificate. The transfer was successful, however, I can't figure out how to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Only these URLs work: www.example.com or https://www.example.com. Following urls are not working:

- example.com
- https://example.com

This is what I did:

1. Created S3 bucket
2. Used Route53 hosting
3. Updated Godaddy name server
4. Generated new AWS certificates for example.com and www.example.com
5. Created two new CNAME
6. Updated record set in Route 53 with those certificate keys.
7. Created two new distribution point in CloudFront
8. Pointed the Alias Target in Route 53 to CloudFront distribution points.

I pretty much followed this tutorial https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/simple-site-hosting-with-amazon-s3-and-https-5e78017f482a/

The error I see is "redirected you too many times." Any help would be great! Search engine still picks up the https://example.com and example.com, which is a bummer.